# JQuery and YUI, can they live together?

Tags: jquery, yui

Can JQuery and YUI live together w/o any conflicts?

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  They live in different namespaces, plus jQuery has a [noConflict option](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict).

Comment: well YUI doesnt' use the $ since that is bad practise anyways (according to Douglas Crowford)

Answer (score 6):

Yes YUI3 uses YUI object, jQuery uses $. For instance you can use YUI 3 Test module and inside it using $ for DOM manipulation/traversing (I think jQuery is really good for those purposes), so for instance you can do:

```
YUI().use("test", function(){
    test : function() {
       $('div li').addClass("example");
       Y.Assert.areEqual("example", $('div li').attr("class"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201768/mixing-jquery-and-yui-together-in-an-app-is-it-easily-possible)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, I do it when necessary.