# Resizable panels in AlloyUI

Tags: javascript, css, layout, panel, alloy-ui

I am learning AlloyUI, but don't know how to set **resizable panels** in **main layout**. I tried [this](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/Plugin.Resize.html) method to resize table, but it didn't work and I didn't see any error in console. Can anybody help how to make **div** elements resizable in AlloyUI?

Here is my basic layout, where are 3 main panels resizable using jQuery UI:

http://jsfiddle.net/vLeve252/

Here is my code, where I tried to make table resizable in panel:

**main.html**

```
    <!-- main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/main.css" media="all" /> 

    <script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>

<div id="layout">

    <div id="filter">

    <table id="tabl" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td> 
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td> 
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    </table>        

    </div>

    <div id="graph"></div>
    <div id="details"></div>

</div> 

<script>
    YUI().use(
  'resize',
  'overlay',
  function (Y) {
    var overlay = new Y.Overlay({
      width: "200px",
      srcNode: "#tabl",
      visible: false,
      align: {node:".example", points:["tc", "bc"]}
   });
   overlay.plug(Y.Plugin.Resize);
  }
);

    </script>

</body>
```

**main.css**

```
#filter{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    border-right:  solid 1px #aaa;
}

#details {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    border-top:  solid 1px #aaa;
}
```

**edit**

I would like to achieve the same result as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vLeve252/), but using AlloyUI not jQuery UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `div`s (or any type of `Node`) resizeable, you need to [`plug()`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_plug) the [`Plugin.Resize`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Plugin.Resize.html) class into your `Node`.

It isn't necessary to use an `Overlay`. Instead you can get the `div`s as [`Node`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html) using [`YUI.one()`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_one). Then you can `plug()` in the `Resize` plug-in. The javascript to do that would look something like this:

```
YUI().use('resize-plugin', 'node', function (Y) {
   Y.one('#filter').plug(Y.Plugin.Resize);
   Y.one('#graph').plug(Y.Plugin.Resize);
   Y.one('#details').plug(Y.Plugin.Resize);
});
```

## Edit:

However, to make a layout similar to the jQuery one that you posted in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLeve252/) is a bit of a tall order. My first recommendation would be to **use jQuery**. The jQuery solution seems to be simple and well thought out, and [**it can coexist with YUI/AlloyUI on the same page**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235236/jquery-and-yui-can-they-live-together), so use jQuery for the layout and YUI/AlloyUI for whatever else you want.

If you absolutely must not use jQuery, you can do something like this:

### HTML

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <div id="details"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#layout {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

#graph {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

#details {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: navy;
}
```

### javascript

```
YUI().use('resize-constrain', 'resize-plugin', 'node', function (Y) {

    var graphNode = Y.one('#graph');
    var detailsNode = Y.one('#details');

    graphNode.plug(Y.Plugin.Resize, {
        handles: ['b']
    });

    graphNode.resize.plug(Y.Plugin.ResizeConstrained, {
        constrain: '#layout'
    });

    graphNode.resize.on('resize:resize', function (event) {
        var graphHeight = parseInt(graphNode.getStyle('height'), 10);
        detailsNode.setStyle('height', (300 - graphHeight) + 'px');
    });
});
```

### Explantion:

1. Plug one `Node` with a `Resize` plugin in order to make it resizable.
2. Plug that `Resize` plugin with a [`ResizeConstrianed`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Plugin.ResizeConstrained.html) plugin in order to only allow resizing within the width of the outer `div`.
3. On the `resize:resize` event:

   - Get the height of the `graph` `div` as an `Integer`.
   - Subtract it from the total height to determine the new height of the `details` `div`.
   - Set the `details` `div` to the new height.

For the sake of completeness, I've included a runnable example with a 3 panel resizable layout much like the jQuery example:

```js
YUI().use('resize-constrain', 'resize-plugin', 'node', function (Y) {

    var graphNode = Y.one('#graph');
    var detailsNode = Y.one('#details');

    graphNode.plug(Y.Plugin.Resize, {
        handles: ['b']
    });

    graphNode.resize.plug(Y.Plugin.ResizeConstrained, {
        constrain: '#rightPanel'
    });

    graphNode.resize.on('resize:resize', function (event) {
        var graphHeight = parseInt(graphNode.getStyle('height'), 10);
        detailsNode.setStyle('height', (300 - graphHeight) + 'px');
    });

    var filterNode = Y.one('#filter');
    var rightPanelNode = Y.one('#rightPanel');

    filterNode.plug(Y.Plugin.Resize, {
        handles: ['r']
    });

    filterNode.resize.plug(Y.Plugin.ResizeConstrained, {
        constrain: '#mainLayout'
    });

    filterNode.resize.on('resize:resize', function (event) {
        var filterWidth = parseInt(filterNode.getStyle('width'), 10);
        var rightPanelResizedWidth = (600 - filterWidth) + 'px';
        rightPanelNode.setStyle('width', rightPanelResizedWidth);
        // YUI sets the height using the `style` attribute, so it must be overwritten using `setStyle()` becuase the CSS has been overriden.
        graphNode.setStyle('width', rightPanelResizedWidth);
    });
});
```

```css
#mainLayout {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
}

#rightPanel {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

#graph {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

#details {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: navy;
}

#filter {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    background: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/0214fdc4cccaa77d6e504320cf70a571/raw/63d260364730fb067f103c00862c7e65685256df/yui-3.18.1_build_yui_yui-min.js"></script>
<div id="mainLayout">
    <div id="rightPanel">
        <div id="graph"></div>
        <div id="details"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="filter"></div>
</div>
```