# Javascript loaders with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, javascript, loader

I'm interested in using a Javascript loader and want to use one which plays nicely with jQuery.  I found this comparison table: https://spreadsheets.google.com/lv?key=tDdcrv9wNQRCNCRCflWxhYQ

However, I'd like to get a recommendation from someone with experience with using any of these with jQuery and jQuery UI.

**Edit:**
The two primary concerns with mixing jQuery and JS loaders are as follows:

- Will there be a namespace conflict?
- Will there be any unexpected behavior?

For namespaces, jQuery's documentation [covers this extensively](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

For unexpected behavior, something you might run into is that the DOM is already in the ready state before jQuery gets loaded in, causing your `$(document).ready(handler)`s to not fire.  You can avoid this by just not using them and assuming your DOM is ready.

If I'm missing others, please comment.

**Resources**
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion, YUI 3 has the best architecture of any JS framework out there.  Their dependency management and dynamic script loading is, therefore, my favorite.  I do love jQuery's simplicity and great community so I've used the two together without too much trouble:

[Mixing jQuery and YUI together in an app, is it easily possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201768/mixing-jquery-and-yui-together-in-an-app-is-it-easily-possible)